# Is there a possibility to run a particular method only once before the whole set of tests in the .cs file run in Nunit

Tags: nunit

I am writing UI tests for a mobile app using Xamarin UI test and N-unit frameworks. I want to run a particular method (App initialization) only once before the set of tests began to run. I used [one time setup] annotation but that is also running before each test.Please help me on this.

Comment: Can you show your code and setup please? The https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/OneTimeSetUp-Attribute should be what you want so perhaps there's something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a `[SetupFixture]` outside of any namespace.

See the docs here: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute